# remove space between divs

Tags: css, whitespace, word-wrap, removing-whitespace

**Question:** Why is there a space between the two div tags?

[Here is the **JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xso35k0y/)

**Screenshot:**

[image]

//HTML

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="sub-item"></div>
        <div class="sub-item"></div>
        <div class="sub-item"></div>
        <div class="sub-item"></div>
        <div class="sub-item"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="sub-item"></div>
        <div class="sub-item"></div>
        <div class="sub-item"></div>
        <div class="sub-item"></div>
        <div class="sub-item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

//CSS

```
.row{
    background-color: red; 

    margin: 2em 0;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.6) inset;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.6) inset;  
}
.item{
    background-color: silver;

    width: 50%;
    white-space: normal;
    display: inline-block;
}
.sub-item{
    background-color: royalblue;

    margin: .5em;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Comment: @Rob yea I've seen the `font-size=0` before, but then it disables my margins on the children `sub-items` in this case.

Comment: Then don't do that. This question is asked all the time so search for those.

Comment: @Rob I want my margins...

Comment: @JordanDavis your margin is using `em`, so if you simple set the `font-size: 0` they will disappear aswell. However you can use `px` for your margins or simple restore the `font-size` in the inner element.

Comment: @Romulo ahhhh damn I don't know how the hell I didn't see that! Thank you thank you!

Comment: @Romulo post that answer I'll mark it, correct. thanks again!

Comment: @JordanDavis my answer already cover that. the margins are working fine :)

Comment: @Romulo got you! yea didn't even see your post yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is there a space between the two div tags?

You can read more about it in [`Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements`](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

To remove the undesired blank space, set `font-size: 0` in the `.row` element, and then restore the `font-size` in the `.item`.

```
.row {
    font-size: 0;
}

.item {
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Since your margins are using the the `em` unit, if you simple set the `font-size: 0` in the wrapper element, your margins will disappear aswell.

To keep your margins, it's important to restore the font-size in the inner element or set the margins using another unit that is not based on the font-size, like `px`.

Following is an example:

```css
.row {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 2em 0;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6) inset;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6) inset;
  font-size: 0;
}
.item {
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: silver;
  width: 50%;
  white-space: normal;
  display: inline-block;
}
.sub-item {
  background-color: royalblue;
  margin: .5em;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="sub-item"></div>
    <div class="sub-item"></div>
    <div class="sub-item"></div>
    <div class="sub-item"></div>
    <div class="sub-item"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="sub-item"></div>
    <div class="sub-item"></div>
    <div class="sub-item"></div>
    <div class="sub-item"></div>
    <div class="sub-item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple ways to remove space between elements...
one way is to simply do have tag literally stick together such as `</div><div>`

```
<div class='row'>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="sub-item"></div>
        <div class="sub-item"></div>
        <div class="sub-item"></div>
        <div class="sub-item"></div>
        <div class="sub-item"></div>
    </div
    ><div class="item"> <-- an end tag stick with another open tag will solve your problem
        <div class="sub-item"></div>
        <div class="sub-item"></div>
        <div class="sub-item"></div>
        <div class="sub-item"></div>
        <div class="sub-item"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For more information on other solutions, you can also look at here [CSS-Trick](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)